# Application of Limits, $v\left(\lambda \right)=\sqrt{\frac{g\lambda }{2\pi }\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda }\right)}$

Tags: limits

$$v\left(\lambda \right)=\sqrt{\frac{g\lambda }{2\pi }\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda }\right)}$$

I have to find the limiting velocities as $\lambda\rightarrow0^+$and $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ of $v(\lambda)$ where $v$ is the phase velocity of the wave, $\lambda>0$ is the wavelength, $g>0$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and $d>0$ is the depth (assumed to be constant).

For $\lambda\rightarrow0^+$, I think I can use the Sandwich rule and for $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, I tried to split the equations into parts and found the limit of $\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda }\right)$ as being $0$ but I don't know where to go from here or if this is the right way of going about the question.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lambda \to \infty$, consider $$v^2=\frac{g \lambda  }{2 \pi }\,\tanh \left(\frac{2 \pi  d}{\lambda }\right)$$ and let $x=\frac{2 \pi  d}{\lambda }$ which makes $$v^2=\frac{d g }{x}\,\tanh (x)$$ and use Taylor expansion around $x=0$ $$\tanh(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ making $$v^2=dg\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right) \right)\implies v=\sqrt{dg}\,\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)}$$ Now, using the generalized binomila theorem $$v=\sqrt{dg}\,\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^3\right)\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: I have not yet been taught the Taylor expansion, is there another method that could be used to solve the question?

Answer (score 1):

$v(x)
=\sqrt{\frac{gx }{2\pi }\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{x }\right)}
$

As $x \to 0$,
$\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{x }\right)
\to 1
$,
so
$v(x)
\approx \sqrt{\frac{gx }{2\pi }}
\to 0
$.

(added later)

This is because
$\tanh(x)
=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}-2e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
=1-\dfrac{2e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
\to 1
$
as
$x \to \infty$.

As $x \to \infty$,
$\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{x }\right)
\approx \frac{2\pi d}{x }
$,
so
$v(x)
\approx \sqrt{\frac{gx }{2\pi }\frac{2\pi d}{x }}
= \sqrt{gd}
$.

(added later)

This is because,
since
$e^x \approx 1+x$
as $x \to 0$,
$\tanh(x)
= \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
\approx \dfrac{(1+x)-(1-x)}{(1+x)+(1-x)}
= \dfrac{2x}{2}
=x
$.

Comment: would you be able to show how $x \to 0,\tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{x }\right)
\to 1 $ and $x \to \infty, \tanh \left(\frac{2\pi d}{x }\right)
\approx \frac{2\pi d}{x }$ as I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

---

$$\tanh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

$$=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}$$

---

By LH,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tanh x}{x}=\lim_{ x \to 0} (\text{sech} x)^2=1$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\tanh (\frac{a}{x})$$

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} a\frac{x}{a}\tanh (\frac{a}{x})= a \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tanh (\frac{a}{x})}{\frac{a}{x}}$$

$$=a \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\tanh u}{u}$$

$$=a$$

Comment: are the limits from hence onwards meant to be $x\to 0$?

Comment: @randb No, infinity. Much like $\lamda \to \infty$.

Comment: Please see edit @randb